# Sharing local storage between different web browsers

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

Is there any way to share the local storage between different instances of web browsers?

At the moment I have a web browser which saves data in the local storage then with an animation another web browser enter the screen, can I use the data saved by the previous browser?

I have seen that in the isostorage there is a directory Internet Explorer/DOMStore/ which contain some sub-directory and for every browser the localstorage is saved in a different directory. There's any way to prevent this and make them save in the same directory?

I hope I made myself clear on the problem

Comment: It will be much simpler to use just one WebBrowser control if you can...

Comment: @PaulAnnetts yeah, that would be great but specs don't permit it, unfortunately the app is not tought to work in a native way, so it kinda suck. Anyway it was resolved using a javascript that set and get the local storage in the pages and during the transition the local storage is passed between the two pages